# ¿Cómo puedo saber que eventos están asociados a un elemento?

Tags: javascript

Si le asocié a un botón el evento on click ¿Cómo compruebo que ya lo tiene para evitar volver a asociarle el evento? por ejemplo, si tengo este código:

```js
document.querySelector("#boton").addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log("Hola");
});
```

```html
<button id="boton">Click </button>
```

Una vez asociado el evento como puedo saber si ya eta asociado seleccionando el elemento con document.querySelector

Answer (score 4):

Buen Día...

El código que te presento a continuación enumera la cantidad de eventos que hay en el dom.

Aquí el código:

```
<script>
        function listAllEventListeners() {
            const allElements = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('*'));
            allElements.push(document);
            allElements.push(window);
          
            const types = [];
          
            for (let ev in window) {
              if (/^on/.test(ev)) types[types.length] = ev;
            }
          
            let elements = [];
            for (let i = 0; i < allElements.length; i++) {
              const currentElement = allElements[i];
              for (let j = 0; j < types.length; j++) {
                if (typeof currentElement[types[j]] === 'function') {
                  elements.push({
                    "node": currentElement,
                    "type": types[j],
                    "func": currentElement[types[j]].toString(),
                  });
                }
              }
            }
          
            return elements.sort(function(a,b) {
              return a.type.localeCompare(b.type);
            });
          }
          console.table(listAllEventListeners())
    </script>
```

Ahora bien, si solo necesitas saber de un elemento cambia el querySelectorAll por el document.getElementById

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementById('boton'));
```

Answer (score 2):

Seleciona el elemento con la consola de desarrollo, puedes abrir la consola y luego presionar el icono de la flecha que se encuentra arriba a la izquierda en chrome y despues debes seleccionar el elemento o puedes usar el atajo de Ctrl+shift+c para selecionar el elemento.

Despues ve a la pestaña de "Event Listener" o "Eventos"

A continuacion podras ver todos los elementos asociados a elemento selecionado.

En tu caso ve a los eventos de tipo "click" y busca el nombre del archivo donde esta escrito el codigo de tu evento.

Answer (score 1):

Si entiendo bien la pregunta, querés saber que eventos se puede usar con este. Entonces simplemente asocia en `consolo.log()` al evento `click` y ya muestra una extensa lista:

```js
document.querySelector("#boton").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  // this.console.log(e);
  console.log(e)
});
```

```html
<button id="boton">Click </button>
```

Pero si necesitas que el `click` actue solamente a éste botón, y no a los demás, entonces prueba el siguiente código.

En caso de que haya muchos botones con el mismo ID, recorre todos con `querySelectorAll`, y luego con `this` ya se le da lo que queremos hacer.

```js
todos = document.querySelectorAll("#boton").forEach(function(este) {
 
  este.addEventListener('click', function() {

this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
console.log("coloreado");
  })
  
});
```

```html
<button id="boton">Click </button>
```

Comment: Por favor, si te funciono la repuesta recuerda "ACEPTAR" para que otros Usuarios se beneficien de ella.

Answer (score 1):

Es un poco complicado trabajar con funciones anónimas al asignar eventos, si no tienes control sobre el momento en que los asignar, se pueden ir acumulando como en este ejemplo:

```js
document.querySelector("#boton").addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log("Hola");
});
// Se acumula al volver a asignar
document.querySelector("#boton").addEventListener("click", () => {
  console.log("Hola");
});
```

```html
<button id="boton">Click </button>
```

Es mejor usar funciones con nombre que, aparte de evitar acumulación, también permite eliminar el evento:

```js
// Declarar función con nombre
function btnClick(e) {
    console.log('Hola');
}

document.querySelector("#boton").addEventListener("click", btnClick);
// No se acumula al volver a asignar
document.querySelector("#boton").addEventListener("click", btnClick);

// Se puede dejar de escuchar el evento
function noClick(e) {
    document.querySelector("#boton").removeEventListener("click", btnClick);
    console.log('El primer botón ya no tiene evento');
}

document.querySelector("#boton2").addEventListener("click", noClick);
```

```html
<button id="boton">Click </button>
<button id="boton2">No click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Mi respuesta llega un poco tarde, pero actualmente con las DevTools podemos ver eso.

Inspeccionas en el elemento que quieres analizar y luego te vienes a la pestaña "Procesadores de Eventos" en la misma barra que los "Estilos" y ahi podras ver los eventos.

Te muestro un ejemplo en el que podemos ver los eventos de tipo Click asociados a un elemento, y debajo todos los demás eventos de otros tipos, focus, focusIn, etc.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]